# Are (relatively) subjective questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, scope

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/290/at-what-age-is-it-good-to-introduce-kids-to-the-raspi

The above question, I think, is rather subjective in that it doesn't have a definitive answer - but then again, it's arguably an important discussion point.

Personally I think such things are best left off the SE site and perhaps more on the official forums, but I'm open to suggestions!

There's other questions that are starting to come into this scope as well: [Will compiled binaries run on other Linux boxes?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/289/is-the-raspi-a-suitable-dev-environment) for example.

Where do we draw the line with these? The latter is better in that it does contain some definitive answerable questions as well, but it's still somewhat subjective.

Answer (score 6):

## No.

Subjective questions shouldn't be allowed as they provide nothing useful to the community. Questions should be answerable.

The first question is an opinion question and has no definitive answer. Ergo, it is subjective and should be closed as not constructive.

The second question is more tricky. It does have some answerable questions in there, but they are buried under subjective questions. In this case, an edit would be preferred to a close vote.

**Note: I've edited the second question and fixed it up.**

Comment: My thoughts exactly, I just wanted to check I was thinking straight!

Answer (score 1):

What about this one?

[Is the Raspberry Pi suitable for running continuously, 24/7?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/325/feasibility-of-24-7-operation)

It's calling for a technical response i.e. yes for these reasons, no for these reasons, possibly based on these 'ifs'.